# How to disallow monkey patching of non-existing methods of mocks?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, monkeypatching, python-unittest

I'd like to write a test that will help me determine whether an API of the library I'm using hasn't changed e.g. after upgrade.

If I'd create a "blind mock" object then the mock will always use the one method and tests will pass, but my the app will break with the actual library.

I know there's a way of patching existing objects:

```
@patch.object(ZipFile, 'namelist')
def test_my_method(self, mocked_zipfile):
```

which will at least check whether the `namelist` method actually exists on the original object, but it still allows me to make a typo when mocking the object inside:

```
@patch.object(ZipFile, 'namelist')
def test_my_method(self, mocked_zipfile):
    mocked_zipfile.namlist.return_value = [ 'one.txt', 'two.txt' ]
```

When I make a typo (`namlist`) inside the test and inside the tested code, the test will just silently pass.

Is there any way I can prevent monkey patching the non-existing methods of mocked object except keeping it in mind every time I write the test (which is not the best way when you have a team and you want to automatically check these things)?

Comment: Why do you need mock at all? If you have a typo, the test will fail - isn't it a desired behavior?

Comment: @alecxe It depends, whether it will fail, it will call the original unmocked method which may fail, but it may not. I need the mock because I'm creating unit tests, not integration tests or any other tests. I want to test the function isolated from other functions & resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch `zipfile.Zipfile` with [`autospec=True`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html):

> If you set `autospec=True` then the mock with be created with a spec
>   from the object being replaced. All attributes of the mock will also
>   have the spec of the corresponding attribute of the object being
>   replaced. Methods and functions being mocked will have their arguments
>   checked and will raise a `TypeError` if they are called with the wrong
>   signature. For mocks replacing a class, their return value (the
>   ‘instance’) will have the same spec as the class.

The following test will fail due to `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'namlist'`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(ZipFile, 'namelist', autospec=True)
    def test_my_method(self, mocked_zipfile):
        mocked_zipfile.namlist.return_value = [ 'one.txt', 'two.txt' ]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `wraps` keyword argument?

This works for me:

```
>>> from mock import Mock
>>> import zipfile
>>> mocked_zipfile = Mock(wraps=zipfile.ZipFile)
>>> mocked_zipfile.namlist.return_value = ['one.txt', 'two.txt']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jbaiter/.envs/spreads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 670, in __getattr__
    wraps = getattr(self._mock_wraps, name)
AttributeError: type object 'ZipFile' has no attribute 'namlist'
>>> mocked_zipfile.namelist.return_value = ['one.txt', 'two.txt']
>>> mocked_zipfile.namelist()
['one.txt', 'two.txt']
```

I haven't tried with a `@patch` decorated method yet, but this should work:

```
@patch('zipfile.ZipFile', Mock(wraps=zipfile.ZipFile))
def test_my_method(self, mocked_zipfile):
    # call code that depends on ZipFile
    pass
```